# App is crashing when using validates_uniqueness_of on Rails with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid on Rails, and added `validates_uniqueness_of :quote` on the model `Quote`.

But whenever there is a repeated record, the app crashes showing this message:

> message: Validation of Quote failed. summary: The following errors
>   were found: Quote is already taken resolution: Try persisting the
>   document with valid data or remove the validations.

This is my model:

```
class Quote
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :quote, type: String
  field :author, type: String
  field :author_about, type: String
  field :tags, type: String

  validates_uniqueness_of :quote
end
```

And this is what I'm trying to do:

```
if @quotedb.save!
    return true
else
    return false
end
```

It should save if its unique, and ignore if its not, but never crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app didn't actually crash, it just throws an exception.

When you calls the `save!` method, the `!` indicate it would trigger the [validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers), and when validation fails, it would raise an exception.

A better approach would be handle the exception using `rescue`, but if you don't care about the validation result, use `save` instead.